Accept payment, mint specific NFT to user's wallet using Metaplex (but not candymachine)
I am trying to setup a simple operation for a user to pay X amount to mint a specific NFT. Have it working on the client only with different code but dont like that the user could just change values on the client.
Here is the button that will kick off the flow and then deserialize and sign the transaction.
const MintButton = () => {
    const { connection } = useConnection();
    const wallet = useWallet();

    const signAndSendTransaction = async (serializedTransaction) => {
        const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
        const umi = createUmi(connection).use(mplCore());
        umi.use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet));

        // how do I deserialize and sign the transaction?
    };

    const handleMint = async () => {
        if (!wallet.publicKey) {
            alert("Please connect your wallet first.");
            return;
        }

        console.log('public Key', wallet.publicKey);
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/api/mint', {
                walletAddress: wallet.publicKey.toString()
            });
            signAndSendTransaction(response.data.transaction);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Minting failed:', error);
            alert("Minting failed, please try again.");
        }
    };

    return <button onClick={handleMint}>Mint NFT</button>;
};

export default MintButton;

Here is the route that accepts the call from the button and calls createMintingTransaction to queue up the necessary transactions.
export async function POST(request) {
    const { walletAddress } = await request.json();
    console.log('request', walletAddress);
    try {
        const transaction = await createMintingTransaction(walletAddress, 0.5);
        return Response.json({ transaction: transaction });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error minting NFT:', error);
        return new Response({ success: false, message: 'Failed to mint NFT.' }, { status: 500 })
    }
}

Lastly here is the createMintingTransaction function
export async function createMintingTransaction(userPublicKey, mintPrice) {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

    const umi = createUmi(new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed")).use(mplCore());

    // Create a keypair from your private key
    const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secretKey));
    umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));

    const asset = generateSigner(umi)
    const result = await createV1(umi, {
        asset,
        name,
        uri,
        collection: publicKey(collectionPubKey),
        owner: publicKey(userPublicKey),
    })

    console.log('result', result);

    const builtTransaction = await result.buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);

    return umi.transactions.serialize(builtTransaction);
}

I have also tried with some of the older APIs
export async function createMintingTransaction(userPublicKey, mintPrice) {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
    const serverKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secretKey));
    const collectionKeypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(collectionSecretKey));
    const feePayer = new PublicKey(userPublicKey); // User will pay the fees
    const treasuryPublicKey = new PublicKey(treasuryPubKeyString);

    // Mint NFT after successful token transaction
    const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(keypairIdentity(serverKeypair));
    // .use(bundlrStorage());
    console.log('created connection', metaplex)

    console.log('get metadata')
    const txBuilder = await metaplex.nfts().builders().create({
        name,
        uri,
        maxSupply: 50,
        updateAuthority: collectionKeypair,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 100, // 1% royalty
        collection: new PublicKey(collectionPubKey),
    });

    const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash());

    const transaction: Transaction = txBuilder.toTransaction({
        blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight
    });
    console.log('get blockhash')
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
    transaction.feePayer = feePayer;

    // Add an instruction to transfer SOL to the treasury or payment account
    transaction.add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: feePayer,
            toPubkey: treasuryPublicKey, // This is your treasury or account receiving the payment
            lamports: mintPrice * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL // Convert SOL to lamports
        })
    );

    transaction.partialSign(serverKeypair);
    transaction.partialSign(collectionKeypair);

    return transaction.serialize({ verifySignatures: false, requireAllSignatures: false }).toString("base64");
}

and the MintButton takes the response and tried to deserialize and sign it. But seems to be missing signatures
const signAndSendTransaction = async (serializedTransaction) => {
        const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
        console.log('trying to sign')
        if (!wallet.connected) {
            console.log("Please connect your wallet");
            return;
        }

        // // Deserialize the transaction sent from the server
        console.log('Deserializing transaction:');
        const transaction = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(serializedTransaction, 'base64'));

        try {
            // Sign the transaction using the user's wallet
            console.log('Signing transaction:', transaction);
            const signedTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
            // Send the signed transaction to the Solana network
            const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());

            // Wait for confirmation of the transaction
            const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'finalized');

            console.log('Transaction confirmed', confirmation);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error signing or sending transaction:', error);
        }
    };

